# Aligning the Lightning Component button is not working as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I am trying to align the button on lightning component to the right but is not working as expected. My component is like below

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  controller="updateCaseRecord">
    <aura:attribute name="updateCase" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Take Ownership" iconPosition="right"  onclick="{!c.updateOwnership}"  />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Close Case" iconPosition="right"  onclick="{!c.updateCaseClose}"  />
</aura:component>
```

Using the lightning App Builder I placed the component in to the Record page but it is not getting aligned to the right

[image]

Even though I have the `iconPosition="right"` it is not getting right justified. I dont have anything on the Style. How can I achieve this.

Also is there any way to add lightning component in to the list of buttons at the top? I know if I can call the lightning component from the Quick action it can be done, since we have Feed Tracking enabled I cannot use Quick Action as they show in the Feed Tab.

After using `slds-float_right`

[image]

And if I am placing the component above the related list quick links like below

[image]

button gets hidden like [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used float on the button  so they are taken out from the "normal" flow you can set overflow to "hidden" or "auto" in this case like this

```
<aura:component Controller="peropertystack" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
<div style="overflow:auto">
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Take Ownership" iconPosition="right" class="slds-float_right" onclick="{!c.updateOwnership}"  />
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Close Case" iconPosition="right" class="slds-float_right" onclick="{!c.updateCaseClose}"  />
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Can you suggest me how to add space between the button I tried to add the class="slds-p-right_x-small"  but cannot but two class on the button

Comment: @user81642 you can add as many classes as you want like this <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Take Ownership"  class="slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right" onclick="{!c.updateOwnership}"  /> also you would need to use "slds-m-left_x-small" class on your first button

Comment: i also suggest you to learn some basic css properties before directly using classes

Answer (score 1):

> `iconPosition` describes the position of the icon with respect to the body.
>   Options include left and right. This value defaults to left.

It does not mean the button floats to right. You need to use the SLDS class for it. `slds-float_right`

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Close Case" iconPosition="right"  onclick="{!c.updateCaseClose}" class="slds-float_right"/>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Take Ownership" iconPosition="right"  onclick="{!c.updateOwnership}" class="slds-float_right"/>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried using `slds-float_right` and added the screen shot above. I want the entire lie to be taken by the component but it gets under the Quick links. Can you please tell me what I am missing here

Comment: @user81642 try wrapping the buttons in the div with `class="slds-box slds-theme_default"`.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old and an answer has been marked as correct, but I had this issue and found that this article worked for me.
https://www.infallibletechie.com/2020/03/how-to-align-lightning-button-in.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.